# SharePoint 2010 backup contents

Tags: backup

Is it possible to get custom tables and stored procedures created in sharepoint site using site backup?

Comment: You should not create custom tables and stored procedures in SharePoint site database itself.. Did I miss something?

Comment: Yes.. But we had scenario to use stored procedures. So only i am asking..